# I need to select last record in database, or record with biggest id

Tags: c#, sql, database, records

```
using (var db = new DbConnection())            
{
    var record = db.Records ....              
}
```

I need to select last record in database or record with biggest id. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Sort your records by `Id` column in *descending* order then get the first record:

```
db.Records.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

use `MAX()` in your SQL Query..

As an Example ( if we want the biggest no of id column of the records-table

```
Select Max(id) from records-table
```

edit : to return record, not only id =>

```
Select id, Name, Description, Date, Owner from records-table where id = (Select Max(id) from records-table)
```

Comment: but that doesn't return the record, it will return the biggest Id value

Comment: From a view of performance this solution is not the best one because it includes a sub select in the wehre clausel.

Comment: @Andre So, if You have another (better) solution in SQL Query Lang; i would pleasure to learn

Comment: The same Selman22 already posted as linq to entity.  SELECT top(1) * from records-table order by Id desc

Comment: @Andre All L2E solutions already converted to raw SQl Queries by L2E engines ;) And do you think SQL Order by descendant faster than Sub-Clause? interesting..Need to check perf ;)